# A single test method returns 2 different or the same output result

Tags: selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, testing

I am trying to run a parallel test using TestNG. When I run the suite sequentially, I don't get any issue having multiple test results in a single method. However, when I try to configure the TestNG Parallelism, a random test fails or passes with two different or the same output result. As a consequence, the parallel execution stops working.

I am getting a result like this:

```
2023-01-26 20:08:44 INFO  Listeners:32 - [Passed] 'verifyUserCanSignUpUsingEmailAccount' test.
2023-01-26 20:08:44 INFO  Listeners:32 - [Failed] 'verifyUserCanSignUpUsingEmailAccount' test.
```

Using TestNG verbose annotation, I got this:

```
2023-01-27 10:46:54 INFO  Listeners:32 - [Failed] 'allPremiumAccountTemplatesAreDisplayed' test. --ThreadID: 28
2023-01-27 10:46:54 INFO  Listeners:32 - [Failed] 'allPremiumAccountTemplatesAreDisplayed' test. --ThreadID: 28
===== Invoked methods
  BaseTest.onStart()[pri:0, instance:tests.Templates.AllPremiumAccountTemplatesAreDisplayed@52227eb2] 1377992370
  BaseTest.methodStartUp()[pri:0, instance:tests.Templates.AllPremiumAccountTemplatesAreDisplayed@52227eb2] 1377992370
    AllPremiumAccountTemplatesAreDisplayed.allPremiumAccountTemplatesAreDisplayed()[pri:0, instance:tests.Templates.AllPremiumAccountTemplatesAreDisplayed@52227eb2] 1377992370
=====
```

Here's my TestNG configuration:

Here is my TestNG file configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test Part 1">   
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.Login.EmailSignUp.VerifyUserCanSignUpUsingEmailAccount"/>
            <class name="tests.Login.EmailSignUp.EmailVerifyTermsAndConditionsAcceptanceMandatory" />
            <class name="tests.Login.EmailSignIn.AcceptTermsAndConditionsAcceptanceViaEmail" />
            <class name="tests.Login.EmailSignUp.VerifyAlreadyRegisteredEmailCannotBeUserAgain" />
            <class name="tests.Login.EmailSignIn.ValidLoginViaEmail" />
        </classes>
    </test>                                
    <test name="Test Part 2">
        <classes>   
            <class name="tests.Templates.AllPremiumAccountTemplatesAreDisplayed"/>
            <class name="tests.navigation.premiumUser.PremiumUserAccessMenuPage"/>
            <class name="tests.navigation.premiumUser.PremiumUserAccessCreatePage"/>
            <class name="tests.navigation.premiumUser.PremiumUserAccessSchedulePage"/>
            <class name="tests.navigation.premiumUser.PremiumUserAccessPlayersPage"/>
        </classes>  
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Here's my BeforeMethod:

```
    @BeforeMethod
    public void methodStartUp() {
        //suiteName = getSuiteName();
        testName = getTestName();
        String[] testName1= testName.split("\\.");
        testName = testName1[testName1.length-1];
        driverManager = new DriverManager();
        setDriver(driverManager.initDriver(getBrowser(),getOS(), testName, suiteName));
        openHomePage();
    }
```

AfterMethod:

```
    @AfterMethod
    public void methodTearDown(ITestResult result) {
        testName = getTestName();
        String[] testName1= testName.split("\\.");
        testName = testName1[testName1.length-1];
        driver.quit();
        threadLocalDriver.remove();
    }
```

Setting a Driver:

```
    public void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        threadLocalDriver.set(driver);
        testName = getTestName();
        String[] testName1= testName.split("\\.");
        testName = testName1[testName1.length-1];
        this.driver = driver;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error for the failed test?

Comment: That is the only error I got. Unfortunately, it doesn't return a detailed stacktrace when running the suite.